# Using OpenAPI3 (swagger) in multiple microservices and generating a single OpenAPI definition

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have a collection of microservices, each with their own complete OpenAPI spec and a root level path

**Microservice Definition**

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: Microservice API
  version: '0.0.1'
paths:
  /:
    get:
      tags:
        - Root
      summary: Root Path
      operationId: Root
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Request was successful
      deprecated: false
  /healthcheck/ping:
    get:
      tags:
        - Healthcheck
      summary: Test the reachability of the microservice.
      operationId: Ping
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Request was successful
      deprecated: false
```

**And a root OpenAPI definition**

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: API
servers:
  - url: http://api.something.com/v1
paths:
  /microservice1:
    $ref: "https://storagebucket.someservice.com/service-definitions/microservice-swagger.yaml"
```

It's been my assumption that it's possible to arrange things this way but I'm getting a whole host of errors in the swagger editor for validity.

Using `microservice-swagger.yaml#/paths/~1` gets me somewhere but I would expect that all the paths in the service yaml to simply be appended to the path in the main definition. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

(The reason behind it being to apply this root swagger to an API Gateway whilst maintaining each service as a self contained unit)

I would for example expect the resulting swagger to offer this as a path

```
/microservice1/healthcheck/ping
```